# Circular Doubly Linked List Copy Constructor C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list, circular-list

I am trying to implement a copy constructor into my Circular Doubly Linked List, but I can not make it work. The files do copy, but not in the correct order. (NOTE: `plate` is defined as `template<typename T>`, and I will try to include the relevant functions only)

Class:

```
plate class CircularDoubleDirectedList : public ICircularDoubleDirectedList<T> {
private:
    plate class Node {
    public:
        T data;
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
    };
    Node<T> *current;
    int nrOfElements;
    direction currentDirection;
public:
    CircularDoubleDirectedList() { nrOfElements = 0; currentDirection = FORWARD; current = nullptr; }
    virtual ~CircularDoubleDirectedList();
    CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& origObj);
    CircularDoubleDirectedList& operator=(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& origObj);
    void addAtCurrent(const T& element);
    T getElementAtCurrent() const;
    void removeAtCurrent();
    int size() const;
    void changeDirection();
    void moveCurrent();
    direction getCurrentDirection() const;
};
```

My try on the copy constructor:

```
plate CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& origObj) {
    current = nullptr;
    nrOfElements = 0;
    Node<T> *tmp = origObj.current;
    currentDirection = origObj.currentDirection;

    while (nrOfElements < origObj.nrOfElements) {
        addAtCurrent(tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
}
```

Adder:

```
plate void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::addAtCurrent(const T& element) {
    Node<T> *tmp = new Node<T>;
    tmp->data = element;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    tmp->prev = nullptr;

    if (current == nullptr) {
        tmp->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = tmp;
        }

    else if (nrOfElements == 1) {
        tmp->next = current;
        tmp->prev = current;
        current->next = tmp;
        current->prev = tmp;
    }

    else {

        if (currentDirection == FORWARD) {
            tmp->prev = current;
            tmp->next = current->next;
            current->next->prev = tmp;
            current->next = tmp;
        }

        else if (currentDirection == BACKWARD) {
            tmp->prev = current->prev;
            tmp->next = current;
            current->prev->next = tmp->prev;
            current->prev = tmp;
        }
    }

    nrOfElements += 1;
    current = tmp;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: The problem seems to be in the last else of the addAtCurrent method. You are updating the nodes in the wrong order. Only to make an example with the direction "backward": current->prev->next = tmp->prev that in turn is current->prev.. and so the element after current->prev is current->prev itself.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okey I fixed my compiler, but I do not get any errors except on the maximum warning level where I get told that I miss several inlines, which I already know. I posted here because I feel that skilled programmers are able to find some problems which the compiler can not. But I will keep the link.

Comment: @RobertoTrani Okey thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: @Henke I didn't say anything about a compiler.  I said use your debugger.  A debugger is a separate tool that allows you to walk through the code as it is executing and lets you observe what is going on.  It is a crucial tool/skill to learn if you want to be a programmer.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, yeah sorry my fault. I wrote compiler instead of debugger... And I know what the debugger does, I may not be an expert with it, but I should not have posted anything here if it told me that something was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comment, the problem seems to be in the last function. So I try to write it from scratch in a more readable way:

```
plate void CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::addAtCurrent(const T& element) {
    Node<T> *tmp = new Node<T>;
    tmp->data = element;

    if (current == nullptr) {
        tmp->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = tmp;
    } else {
        Node<T> * before, after;
        if (currentDirection == FORWARD) {
            before = current;
            after = current->next;
        } else {  // BACKWARD
            before = current->prev;
            after = current;
        }

        before->next = tmp;
        tmp->prev = before;
        after->prev = tmp;
        tmp->next = after;
    }

    nrOfElements += 1;
    current = tmp;
}
```

I see another problem in the copy constructor: if the currentDirection is Backward you are reading the elements from left to right, but adding the elements in a "afterward" fashion, with a consequent loss of the order.
There are two solutions: you can respect the order during the scan, or set the currentDirection to FORWARD and then set it to the right value.

```
plate CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>::CircularDoubleDirectedList(const CircularDoubleDirectedList<T>& origObj) {
    current = nullptr;
    nrOfElements = 0;
    currentDirection = FORWARD;  // set the scan direction temporarily

    for (Node<T> *tmp = origObj.current; nrOfElements < origObj.nrOfElements; tmp = tmp->next) {
        addAtCurrent(tmp->data);
    }
    if (nrOfElements > 0)
        current = current->next;  // align with the current of the copyed list
    currentDirection = origObj.currentDirection;  // set the right direction
}
```

please let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you! I have been trying to fix this for so long.